# Why div inside a overflow: hidden; div not taking full width of it's content?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
}
.list-item {
  display: 'inline-block',
  boxSizing: 'border-box',
  border: '3px solid black'
}



import React, { Component } from 'react'



function calcItemWidth(width, tiles) {
  return width / tiles
}

export class Container extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);

  }

  get container() {
    return document.querySelector('.container');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const itemwidth = calcItemWidth(this.container.clientWidth, 2)

    const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
    Array.from(listItems)
      .map(item => {
        item.style.width = `400px`; 
      })
  }

  renderChildren() {
    return this.props.children.map(
      (child, index) => (
        <li key={child.key} data-index={index} className="list-item" style={listItem}>
          {child}
        </li>
      )
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={container} className="container">
        {this.renderChildren()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Container
```

I have a component called `container`. `Container` has a fixed width of 800px and has `overflow hidden`. Inside `container`, I have `inner`, I want `inner` to be width of the elements it contains. So if I have 4 `listItems`, inner should be 1600px wide.

I tried set the width of inner to `width: 100%` and `min-width: 100%` etc, but it's not taking the width of its children. How to make inner expand beyond the width of the container?

EDIT: The overflow of inner doesn't have to be visible nor have a slider. It just has to be physically the total width of its children.

Comment: When inner is 1600px and container is 800px, you then want to show a horizontal scrollbar? If so, the overflow: hidden will prevent that.

Comment: @Flink, no need for horizontal slider, inner just needs to be able to have width bigger than container based on the width of its content.

Comment: @Flink added a demo

Comment: Ah now i see what you want. But Alberto already solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to `inner` class